# Accessing hidden inherited member

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

Please look at the following code:

```
struct NodeA{
    int a;
};

struct NodeB : public NodeA{
    int b;
};

struct GraphA{
    NodeA* nodes; //array of nodes
};

struct GraphB : public GraphA{
    NodeB* nodes; //array of nodes
};
```

If I now operate on an instance of struct `GraphB` and cast it to an instance of `GraphA`, is it true that the `nodes` variable is not the same in the cast instance as in the instance of `GraphB`?

Is there a pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: In y our code, `GraphB` will have to sets of nodes (`GraphA::nodes` and `GraphB::nodes`), do you really need this? Why don't you use `GraphA::nodes` only (a `NodeA*` can point to a `NodeA` or a `NodeB` since `NodeB` inherits from `NodeA`)?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if you want an array of structures in C++, firstly use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of raw pointers.

Comment: More related to your problem, while `NodeA` and `NodeB` might be related, I don't see the same relationship between `GraphA` and `GraphB`. Maybe you should rethink your design? If there's some common attributes or member functions between `GraphA` and `GraphB`, then consider using a common and generic base class `Graph` instead. You could even make a templated `Graph` class and make `GraphA` and `GraphB` be type-aliases of the templated `Graph` class.

Comment: This is only a sample code i forgot to mention that sorry. Ok so there are two "nodes" member in the inherited variant. I am debugging a software and found a design like this and i also wondered. A generic class will not work because there are functions implemented in GraphB that override those of GraphA and do other stuff based on the other node type. I think removing the nodes member of struct GraphB and cast the nodes would be the solution. thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I now operate on an instance of struct `GraphB` and cast it to an instance of `GraphA`, is it true that the `nodes` variable is not the same in the cast instance as in the instance of `GraphB`?

Yes and no. Each instance of `GraphB` actually contains two data members named `nodes`: one declared in `GraphA` (whose fully-qualified name is `::GraphA::nodes`) and one declared in `GraphB` (whose fully-qualified name is `::GraphB::node`).

When you use just the name `nodes`, such as in `g.nodes`, it will depend on the static type of `g`. If `g` is a (reference to) `GraphA`, it will refer to `GraphA::nodes` (of type `NodeA*`). If `g` is a (reference to) `GraphB`, it will refer to `GraphB::nodes` (of type `NodeB*`).

As to how you can "solve this problem:" that's unclear, since you didn't quite specify what the problem is. If you need to access `GraphA::node` through a reference to `GraphB`, you can do it by explicit qualification:

```
GraphB *g;
g->GraphA::nodes = /*whatever*/
```

If you want to access `GraphB::nodes` through a reference to `GraphA`, you can't. That's what the C++ type system is designed to prevent. If you need to access a memeber of `GraphB`, go through something typed as `GraphB`.

Comment: `If you want to access GraphB::nodes through a reference to GraphA, you can't.` one option would be a virtual method that gets the nodes.

Comment: @GillBates Well, yes and no again. You could access the pointer value, but it would most likely be typed as `NodeA*`. Because having a virtual returning `NodeB*` inside `GraphA` would be an abomination of a design.